# How update a view when observable subcription changes on angular 6?

Tags: rxjs, angular7

I have a service which is publishing objects on an observable, but when I update an  array using a subscription, the new object does not display on the list (html):

```js
export class PublicationService {
// ... more code ...
getAllPapersOnState(state: string): Observable<Paper> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.WF_SC.deployed().then(instance => {

        // State changed watcher to update on-live the observable
        const event = instance.AssetStateChanged({});
        event.on('data', (data) => {
          console.log('StateChanged catched!');
          this.getPaper((data['args']['assetAddress'])).then((paper) => observer.next(paper));
        });

        // TODO Filter by asset type
        return instance.findAssetsByState.call(state);
      }).then(addresses => {
        addresses.forEach((address) => this.getPaper(address).then((paper) => observer.next(paper)));
      });
    });
  }
}

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  papersSubmitted$:Observable<DataCard>;
  papersOnReview$:Observable<DataCard>;
  papersPublished$:Observable<DataCard>;

  constructor(private publicationService: PublicationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.papersSubmitted$ = this.publicationService.getAllPapersOnState("Submitted").pipe(
      map(paper => HomeComponent.paperToCard(paper,'Read', 'Review'))
    );
    this.papersOnReview$ = this.publicationService.getAllPapersOnState("OnReview").pipe(
      map(paper => HomeComponent.paperToCard(paper,'Read', 'Accept'))
    );
    this.papersPublished$ = this.publicationService.getAllPapersOnState("Published").pipe(
      map(paper => HomeComponent.paperToCard(paper,'Read', ''))
    );
  }
  // ... more code ...

}
<app-cardlist
  [title]="'Published'"
  [description]="'Last science papers published. Yay!'"
  [collection$]="papersPublished$"
  (clickActionCard)="clickActionCardHandlePublished($event)"></app-cardlist>
<app-cardlist
  [title]="'On Review'"
  [description]="'Last papers on review. On publish way!'"
  [collection$]="papersOnReview$"
  (clickActionCard)="clickActionCardHandleOnReview($event)"></app-cardlist>
<app-cardlist
  [title]="'Submitted'"
  [description]="'Last papers submitted for reviewing. Be the first one to check them!'"
  [collection$]="papersSubmitted$"
  (clickActionCard)="clickActionCardHandleSubmitted($event)"></app-cardlist>

export class CardlistComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() title;
  @Input() description;
  @Input() collection$: Observable<DataCard>;
  items:DataCard[] = [];
  subscription:Subscription;

  @Output() clickActionCard: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.collection$.subscribe((data_card:DataCard) => {
      console.log(data_card);
      this.items.push(data_card);
      console.log(this.items);
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
<div *ngIf="(items)" class="card-deck">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{item['title']}}</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{item['subtitle']}}</h6>
        <p class="card-text">{{item['description']}}</p>
        <a href="#" (click)="onClickAction(1, item)" class="card-link">{{item['action_1_name']}}</a>
        <a href="#" (click)="onClickAction(2, item)" class="card-link">{{item['action_2_name']}}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The new object published on observable $collection should be displayed on the CardList but nothing is refreshed although console.log(data_card) show the new object.

Repository code: [HomeComponent](https://github.com/smartpublish/SMART-Publish-Research/tree/dev/webapp/src/app/modules/home/pages), [CardListComponent](https://github.com/smartpublish/SMART-Publish-Research/tree/dev/webapp/src/app/shared/layout/cardlist)

Comment: Phew, big question. I'll take a look if i can find the time to have a proper look, but i do have one remark: its bad practice to put observables as Input() on components. If you want to pass the values of an observable to a component set its attribute like this: collection="papersSubmitted$|async". Actually, it might be the cause of your issue: if your input property is an instance of an observable, change detection might not kick in because the instance of your observable never changes. Use the async pipe and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: It says: `The pipe 'async' could not be found` on runtime

Comment: Actually I refactorized the code using `BehaviorSubject<Array<DataCard>>.asObservable()` but althought I can see on the console the subscription inside CardListComponent (child) working right and showing new items which are arriving, the view is not refreshed.

Code is on this repo:
https://github.com/smartpublish/SMART-Publish-Research/tree/dev/webapp/src/app/shared/layout/cardlist
https://github.com/smartpublish/SMART-Publish-Research/tree/dev/webapp/src/app/modules/home/pages